# Some mobile phone gets the error "android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file "of SlidingMenu

Tags: android, slidingmenu, android-inflate

My app is all right on most of the phone.However,on some kinds of phone,it will get the error below:

```
android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #2: Error inflating class com.jeremyfeinstein.slidingmenu.lib.SlidingMenu
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1686)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1702)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1600(ActivityThread.java:118)
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:952)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:130)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3768)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:839)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:597)
    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #2: Error inflating class com.jeremyfeinstein.slidingmenu.lib.SlidingMenu
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:518)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:570)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:386)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:320)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:276)
    at com.jeremyfeinstein.slidingmenu.lib.app.a.a(Unknown Source)
    at com.jeremyfeinstein.slidingmenu.lib.app.SlidingFragmentActivity.onCreate(Unknown Source)
    at com.qingdaonews.bus.BaseActivity.onCreate(Unknown Source)
    at com.qingdaonews.activity.MainActivity.onCreate(Unknown Source)
    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1046)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1650)
    ... 11 more
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.constructNative(Native Method)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:415)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:505)
    ... 21 more
Caused by: java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: Can't convert to dimension: type=0x1
    at android.content.res.TypedArray.getDimensionPixelSize(TypedArray.java:463)
    at android.view.View.(View.java:2096)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.(ViewGroup.java:294)
    at android.widget.RelativeLayout.(RelativeLayout.java:178)
    at com.jeremyfeinstein.slidingmenu.lib.SlidingMenu.(Unknown Source)
    at com.jeremyfeinstein.slidingmenu.lib.SlidingMenu.(Unknown Source)
```

And this phone's Android version is 2.3.5 which my app is support(It's fine on other 2.3.5 phones).So I'm confused about that why only this kind of phone will get the error and I don't know how to fix it.

The xml of layout is ver sample:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<com.jeremyfeinstein.slidingmenu.lib.SlidingMenu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/slidingmenumain"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" /><br>
```

And the main class is here [jfeinstein10 slidingmenu](https://github.com/jfeinstein10/SlidingMenu/blob/master/library/src/com/jeremyfeinstein/slidingmenu/lib/SlidingMenu.java)

Answer (score 1):

It says you are using some of the API which doesn't exist on 2.3.5.
Do you use some attributes of the `RelativeLayout` in your sliding menu layout which do not exist on previous Android versions? Such as `android:layout_alignParentEnd` for instance

Comment: Thank you.But it's fine on other 2.3.5 phones and I did not use some api over 2.3.5

Comment: can you post you sliding menu layout xml file? The problem is obviously there :)

Comment: I don't see anything wrong here and according to logcat it crashes right in the View's constructor (before these scary layout manipulations from `SlidingMenu` class). So I would assume your device has some custom Android build (not the official one) which throws this exception. I just checked line 2096 of View's implementation in 2.3.5. And it doesn't call `getDimensionPixelSize`, so that's why I assume this is custom build (some CyanogenMod or similar)..

Comment: Thank you very much.It is a custom build but there are many customs use this kind of rom so I wonder the reason of this in order to fix the problem.It is too confused to fix problem in custom build

Comment: Yeap.. It is really hard to understand what is going on without access to custom rom's `View` implementation. What I would do - is I would play with `width` and `height` params. Try to change it to `match_parent`. Dumb suggestion, I know, but sometimes even dumbest idea work :)

Comment: Thank you.I'll try it. Without dimen the UI performence may be not as good as used but as you say, dumb idea usually works

Answer (score 0):

For Android Studio 3.0.1

I have got the same issue and I have resolved finally Opening the `gradle.properties` and added following line:

`android.enableAapt2=false`